# VBoxLinuxAdditions.run caused and error: incompatible type for argument

Tags: debian, virtualbox

while running `sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` I got the bellow error with Kernel 4.16 on debian testing:

```
tmp/vbox.0/vbox_ttm.c: In function ‘vbox_bo_move’:
/tmp/vbox.0/vbox_ttm.c:208:29: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘ttm_bo_move_memcpy’
  r = ttm_bo_move_memcpy(bo, interruptible, no_wait_gpu, new_mem);
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /tmp/vbox.0/vbox_drv.h:66:0,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/vbox_ttm.c:31:
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.16.0-1-common/include/drm/ttm/ttm_bo_driver.h:1001:5: note: expected ‘struct ttm_operation_ctx *’ but argument is of type ‘bool {aka _Bool}’
 int ttm_bo_move_memcpy(struct ttm_buffer_object *bo,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/vbox.0/vbox_ttm.c:208:44: error: incompatible type for argument 3 of ‘ttm_bo_move_memcpy’
  r = ttm_bo_move_memcpy(bo, interruptible, no_wait_gpu, new_mem);
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /tmp/vbox.0/vbox_drv.h:66:0,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/vbox_ttm.c:31:
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.16.0-1-common/include/drm/ttm/ttm_bo_driver.h:1001:5: note: expected ‘struct ttm_mem_reg *’ but argument is of type ‘bool {aka _Bool}’
 int ttm_bo_move_memcpy(struct ttm_buffer_object *bo,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/vbox.0/vbox_ttm.c:208:6: error: too many arguments to function ‘ttm_bo_move_memcpy’
  r = ttm_bo_move_memcpy(bo, interruptible, no_wait_gpu, new_mem);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /tmp/vbox.0/vbox_drv.h:66:0,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/vbox_ttm.c:31:
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.16.0-1-common/include/drm/ttm/ttm_bo_driver.h:1001:5: note: declared here
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your virtualbox version?

Comment: I would advise running a Debian stable version to avoid this kind of problems.

Comment: Virtualbox version is 5.2.10 r122088 (qt5.6.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade to VirtualBox 5.2.12 which [adds support for version 4.16 of the kernel](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog#12).

Since you’re running testing, you could install [the `virtualbox` package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/virtualbox) instead, at least once version 5.2.12 migrates to testing.